# NSMutableDictionary not having values set for no obvious reason

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutabledictionary

I have the following code:

```
//in .h file: NSMutableDictionary* expandedSections;
//in Init method: expandedSections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Key: %@", key);
    if ([expandedSections objectForKey:key] == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Value Should be: %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]);
        [expandedSections setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:key];
    }
    else
    {
        [expandedSections setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:![[expandedSections objectForKey:key] boolValue]] forKey:key];
    }
    NSLog(@"Value: %@", [expandedSections objectForKey:key]);
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (float) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Key: %@", key);
    NSLog(@"Value: %@", [expandedSections objectForKey:key]);
    if ([expandedSections objectForKey:key] == nil || ![[expandedSections objectForKey:key] boolValue])
    {
        return 44;
    }
    else
    {
        return 88;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting this to output to the log an alternating value of 1 and 0 when I tap a row in my UITableView.  And correspondingly, expand and collapse the row I tap.

For some reason, the NSDictionary, never has any key/value pairs in it, so as a consequence the rows never expand.  THe logging from heightForRow method comes out as:

```
2012-02-08 11:36:30.291 MappApp[5040:707] Key: 0
2012-02-08 11:36:30.293 MappApp[5040:707] Value: (null)
```

The logging from didSlectRowAt method comes out as:

```
2012-02-08 11:36:44.551 MappApp[5040:707] Key: 0
2012-02-08 11:36:46.530 MappApp[5040:707] Value Should be: 1
2012-02-08 11:36:50.723 MappApp[5040:707] Value: (null)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Make it an NSMutableDictionary

Comment: It is an NSMutableDictionary in my code - that was a typo in the comment

Comment: Can you Pl. differentiate the NSLog's in didSelect.. and heightFor.. methods?

Comment: @Aadhira Updated question with clarification on origin of log messages...

Comment: I hope you have not init the dictionary properly. May I know where exactly you are initiating that, considering your's as subclass of UIViewController or UITableViewController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logging output makes sense if `expandedSections` is `nil`, i.e. you never created it or reset it for some reason.

You should start by checking the initialization code for your class.

Comment: Thankyou - that was indeed the correct answer - my init was never being called...